# WCF - Can I generate one proxy from two separate interfaces

Tags: wcf, wcf-proxy

I have two separate interfaces and two separate endpoints (.svc files) defined in a single WCF project. These interfaces share common objects in the project. Is there a way to create a single proxy that combines both interfaces and all the objects, since they are shared?

Thanks!

Comment: marc, while searching here, I ended up finding another thread (I lost the url) which suggested using the following svc syntax: svcutil.exe /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /ser:Auto /tcv:Version35 /n:*,MyNamespace 
http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service1.svc?wsdl http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service2.svc?wsdl http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service3.svc?wsdl By doing this, I was able to create a single proxy which had three interfaces and three client classes, but all objects that were common in the implementation appeared only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching here, I ended up finding another thread (I lost the url) which suggested using the following svc syntax:

> svcutil.exe
>   /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   /ser:Auto /tcv:Version35
>   /n:*,MyNamespace 
>   http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service1.svc?wsdl
>   http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service2.svc?wsdl
>   http://localhost/MyService/Services/Service3.svc?wsdl

By doing this, I was able to create a single proxy which had three interfaces and three client classes, but all objects that were common in the implementation appeared only once.

Comment: Very interesting indeed ! I had no idea (but frankly also never tried) you could do this! Thanks for sharing! (wish you'd find that URL again - wouldn't it be in your browser's history somewhere??)

Comment: Unfortunately it was on a different computer. Basically in the answer, the posted gave a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx If you look in the syntax, the <url> parameter is marked with a * indicating 0 or more instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement multiple interfaces in one service:

```
public class MyService : IContract1, IContract2
{

}
```

Then you can have a proxy for that service that uses both contracts.